# How can I filter by Matrix field

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field and I want to be able to filter by it.

For example I want to get all entries that has `matrixField.field1Type.value = {some value}.`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can query Matrix blocks like you are used to with all other elements

```
{% set blocks = element.matrixFieldHandle.type('typeHandle').field('some value').all() %}
```

Keep in mind your `field` should be a valid field handle within your block type

Comment: I'm trying to get all entries with given field value, not all blocks.

Comment: You can either use the search parameter or do something like this https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26447/element-query-matrixfields-where

Comment: What do you mean by search parameter?

Comment: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html but you need to leave the field parameter blank - > you'll get all results with the search term not just the results for a certain field. Another method would be to filter for matrixBlocks directly and get their owner. It's easier but resource heavy https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/twig/variables/CraftVariable.php#L288 `set blocks = craft.matrixBlocks.typeId(x).fieldHandle(value). all()` then loop the result and query their owner

Comment: Or even better `entryIds = craft.matrixBlocks...... select('ownerId').column()` and then filter for those ids